# Installing a plugin in Redmine running in OpenShift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins, openshift

I'm running Redmine 2.0.3 in OpenShift. It's a Ruby 1.9 cartridge installed with `https://github.com/ramr/redmine-2.0-openshift-quickstart`. I'm trying to install redmine_charts2 (`https://github.com/pharmazone/redmine_charts2`). I've followed the instructions, keeping in mind that it's Rails 3 and Redmine 2. For example, plugins must be at `plugins` folder, not `vendor/plugins`.

When I go to `administration --> information` everything seems fine, but it says

`Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed`
 

Error log displays no error message.

I tried moving plugins to `vendor/plugins` and it obviously fails.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a git submodule in plugins/ and add in the post_deploy hook :
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

Answer (score 2):

@rclsilver actually solved my issues. There're the details:

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/pharmazone/redmine_charts2 plugins/redmine_charts2
vim .openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy
git rm --cached plugins/redmine_charts2
git submodule update --init
```